# Dynamically added html vs static html differs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can't understand why dynamically html differs from static html. Output seems to be the same when looking in developer tools.

What I want is to have the static html look like dynamically added html, so no spacing between elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var parentElement = $("#dynamic");
  parentElement.html("");
  var html = "";
  html += "<button>-</i></button>";
  html += "<input type='number' value='1' />";
  html += "<button>+</button>";
  $(html).appendTo(parentElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic">
  
</div>

<div>
  <button>-</button>
  <input type='number' value='2' />
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the difference between your static and dynamic html is that in your static html you actually have text node betweem the first button element and the input element, same for between the input element and the second button, the browser reduces all this white space to a single white space character, thats how browsers render html

Comment: You have actual spaces between the elements in HTML that you don’t have in the JS generated version.

Comment: I've made a subtle change to the static HTML so it's clearer which is based on the HTML and which has been added dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN will tell you [How is whitespace handled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace)

So let's try a [zero width font](https://github.com/patrickkunka/zero-width) inspired by [this answer to How to remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20473553/295783))

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dynamic").html(`<button>-</button><input type="number" value="1" /><button>+</button>`)
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/font-zero-width/latest/zero-width.css');
.zerowidth {
  font-family: 'zero-width';
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic" class="zerowidth">

</div>

<div class="zerowidth">
  <button>-</button>
  <input type="number" value="1" />
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

If you do not want to do it using a font, then you need to  inline the tags removing all whitespaces if you do not want any space between the elements

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dynamic").html(`<button>-</button><input type="number" value="1" /><button>+</button>`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic">

</div>

<div><button>-</button><input type="number" value="1" /><button>+</button></div>
```

Alternatively remove the whitespace around the tags and copy the HTML or clone the existing div content

```js
$(function() {
  const $source = $("#source");
  const html = $source.html().replace(/\s+(?=<)|(?<=>)\s+/g, '');
  $source.html(html)
  $("#dynamic").html(html)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic">

</div>

<div id="source">
  <button>-</button>
  <input type="number" value="1" />
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [...source.childNodes].forEach(node=>node.nodeType===Node.TEXT_NODE&&node.remove());

Comment: @mattrichards I think my regex is faster and in this specific case acceptable (as is do not use regex on HTML).